# Windows Server 2012 r2 не загружается после обновления

Tags: windows, update

На Windows Server 2012 r2 не получается установить обновления. Обновление загружается, устанавливается и требует перезагрузку сервера, но после перезагрузки сервер не загружается в нормальном режиме. Получается загрузиться только в режиме обслуживания и откату на предыдущее состояние.

Comment: Ну значит хреново обновился. Грохни проблемную кбшку и внеси её в блеклист.

Comment: Не не получается, установка любого обновления приводит к такой ситуации.

Comment: Какая sha1 у iso-шки с которой ставишь?

Comment: Систему ставил не я. Не могу ответить на этот вопрос.

Comment: Ок. А физический доступ\ipmi есть?

Comment: ipmi скорее всего нет, но сервер supermicro, нужно уточнить. Физически доступ только непосредственный :)

Comment: Я к тому, что может тот, кто ставил - поставил или битый образ или какую-нить сборку "я у мамы админ". Наш образ скачанный с msdn выглядит так: `ru_windows_server_2012_r2_with_update_x64_dvd_4048519.iso`. `SHA1: 1844C87F78607570B3EAEB29788E6605D9C09056` Всё ок и как файлопомойка и как контроллер и как remoteapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. На самом деле нужно было просто посмотреть на ошибку которую выдает система при загрузке. Ошибка была вот такая: kmode_exception_not_handled (aksdf.sys). Это драйвер аппаратного ключа Sentinel, который не использовался. Я просто удалил этот файл и все упоминания в реестре о нем.